# yii2 gridview allow rows to render html

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I need to render html on gridview rows.

I've tried this but then it renders that html on all rows, but I just want it to render on the first row..

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => [
    [
       'label'=>'bla',
       'format' => 'raw',
       'value'=>function ($data) {
            return \yii\helpers\Html::dropDownList("test", null, [0=>"hello",1=>"hello2"]);
        },
    ],
],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function like this:

```
'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
```

$index should contain the number of the showed row. So you can do a:

```
'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        if(!$index)
            return \yii\helpers\Html::dropDownList("test", null, [0=>"hello",1=>"hello2"]);
 },
```